# WebFlux DataBufferLimitException: Part headers exceeded the memory usage limit of 8192 bytes

Tags: java, netty, spring-webflux, project-reactor

When uploading a csv file and a JSON object at the following endpoint

```
@PostMapping(value = "dataset/rows/query", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
Mono<List<Integer>> getRowsByQuery(@RequestPart("dataset") Mono<FilePart> file, 
                                   @RequestPart("query") QueryDTO query){
    return Mono.just(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

I get the following error:

```
2020-12-17 12:25:05.142 ERROR 195281 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [d418565e-17]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/dataset/rows/query"

org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Part headers exceeded the memory usage limit of 8192 bytes
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartParser$HeadersState.onNext(MultipartParser.java:360) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/dataset/rows/query" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartParser$HeadersState.onNext(MultipartParser.java:360) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartParser.hookOnNext(MultipartParser.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartParser.hookOnNext(MultipartParser.java:46) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.BaseSubscriber.onNext(BaseSubscriber.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:265) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:371) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:381) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:535) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:229) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:425) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.54.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.54.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.54.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

I tried to customize the `defaultCodex().maxinMemorySize()` by

```
@Component
public class ServerConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

and the following application.yml

```
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT:8080}
  max-http-header-size: 900000000
spring:
  codec:
    max-in-memory-size: 900000000
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Moreover, what is strange is that the error on the server side only seems to happen when calling the API from Angular, but not from postman.

From **Angular** I have the following headers:

```
POST /dataset/rows/query HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 496570
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySBh6gJvnTeDzB43Y
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:4200/app
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ru-RU;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4
```

and finally, this is the corresponding OpenAPI yaml for the endpoint:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: OpenAPI definition
  version: v0
servers:
- url: http://localhost:8080
  description: Generated server url
paths:
  /dataset/rows/query:
    post:
      tags:
      - dataset-controller
      operationId: getRowsByQuery
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                dataset:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
                query:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/QueryDTO'
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: integer
                  format: int32
components:
  schemas:
    PredicateDTO:
      type: object
      properties:
        value:
          type: object
        key:
          type: string
        operator:
          type: string
          enum:
          - EQUAL
          - NOT_EQUAL
          - BELONGING
          - NOT_BELONGING
          - GREATER_THAN
          - GREATER_THAN_EQUAL
          - LESS_THAN
          - LESS_THAN_EQUAL
    QueryDTO:
      type: object
      properties:
        predicates:
          type: object
          additionalProperties:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PredicateDTO'
```

Here is my [dataset](https://pastebin.com/raw/QuethDg6) and my [json object](https://pastebin.com/raw/qBRGxLJr).
How can I increase the Part headers memory usage limit?

Comment: please share the Spring boot version

Comment: @1Z10 did you find any solution, facing same issue, for us its working both in angular and postman, however in our case the upload fails for first upload then on it works. found this issue on version 2.4.1, did not find any issue in 2.4.2, but now again in 2.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
As of Spring 5.3.13, the default `maxHeadersSize` in the `DefaultPartHttpMessageReader` class is 10KiB instead of the previous 8KiB. See [this Github commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/0416168d0edfaa8f321e318bd4129df7b425ee79). Try updating the version of Spring you are using to at least this version and hopefully your issue will be resolved.

**Original answer below**:

---

You were on the right track.

According to the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-limits), you have to provide your own `MultipartHttpMessageReader` if you want to customize any of the pre-defined limits:

> For Multipart parsing the maxInMemorySize property limits the size of non-file parts. For file parts, it determines the threshold at which the part is written to disk. For file parts written to disk, there is an additional maxDiskUsagePerPart property to limit the amount of disk space per part. There is also a maxParts property to limit the overall number of parts in a multipart request. To configure all three in WebFlux, you’ll need to supply a pre-configured instance of MultipartHttpMessageReader to ServerCodecConfigurer.

The docs don't seem to mention anything about the part header size limit referred to in the stack trace. However, for me, that was the only property I needed to increase from the defaults to fix the issue, but you could easily customize any of the other default limits of the `DefaultPartHttpMessageReader`.

```
@Configuration
public class CodecConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultPartHttpMessageReader partReader = new DefaultPartHttpMessageReader();
        partReader.setMaxHeadersSize(9216); // 9 KiB, default is 8 KiB
        partReader.setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(true);

        MultipartHttpMessageReader multipartReader = new MultipartHttpMessageReader(partReader);
        multipartReader.setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(true);

        configurer.defaultCodecs().multipartReader(multipartReader);
    }
}
```